# Angular translate works on VS locally but not on the server why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a test site that works when i run it on visual studio. it translate perfectly.
but on the server it does'nt. i know angularits there because i'm using ui.router and its working the link and everything but not the translate.
again on vs works.

what can it be? thanks
it only shows my prefixes http://m3rca.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Notice that get `http://m3rca.azurewebsites.net/lang/en/Resource.json` return **404**.

Comment: Thanks Yin.
but the url is correct look:
\lang\en\Resource.json

$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
        urlTemplate: 'lang/{lang}/{part}.json'

what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This solve it. thanks